# How do I evaluate a statement in a Snowflake Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a need to create a calculation using a JSON document. Using a simple example like 10+10-3, I want to eval the statement but Snowflake javascript doesn't allow me to evaluate the statement, has anyone figured out how to evaluate a result of a json based calculation? I have been able to assign each input to a variable then execute a select statement to get the result, however it is fairly labor intensive.

Comment: The script of your procedure or an example would be helpful in our understanding of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: My code contained too many references to proprietary data. This question is basically an ask for any ideas around how to evaluate a calculation that is defined in a "Table" the real calculations are very complex, and have multiple steps. I am using a json document with a structure that define how the calculations should be executed. Creating views is not an option due to there being 1000's of custom calcs with dependencies on what customer is used. Currently I am passing the definition to Python, but ultimately it would be better to have everything done in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

The `eval()` function indeed gives the error: `JavaScript execution error: Uncaught EvalError: Dynamic code evaluation disallowed`.

One workaround is to inject the expression into a SELECT statement, like this:

```
create or replace procedure p(S varchar)
returns number
language javascript
as
$$
    const rs = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: `SELECT ${S}` })
    rs.next()
    return rs.getColumnValue(1)
$$;

call p('1+1');
```

But beware of SQL injection.  Or implement a simple javascript infix expression parser.

Comment: Yes I used the methdology, however I have 1000's of calcs, and they have multiple steps, each one is different in length and steps.

Comment: A single SELECT statement can have a large number of multi-step arithmatic expressions.  (And potentially execute in parallel across the cluster.) .  But are we talking about arithmetic expressions or arbitrary javascript programs/algorithms?  In any case the only way I know of to execute dynamic javascript from within a Snowflake procedure would be to have the procedure create create a UDF and then call it.  I tested it and it works but is quite a hack.